# What is the equivalent of "here" (offering sb sth)

Tags: colloquial, interjection

I know "bitte sehr/schön." Is it possible to say "hier" akin to in English?

I'm looking for the equivalent with the same level of casualness, like when you hand something to a toddler after they asked for it.

Papa, Milch bitte.

OK, Moment.  [...] Hier! (??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *hier* is used in a similar manner in German. For example, when someone asks

> A: „Gibst du mir bitte den Stift?“
>   
>   <sup>(A: "Would you give me the pen, please?")</sup>

then an you can respond

> B: „*Hier* hast du ihn.“
>   
>   <sup>("Here you are.")</sup>

or

> B: „*Hier* ist er.“
>   
>   <sup>("Here it is")</sup>

or even more succinctly

> B: „*Hier*, (bitte schön).“

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in such informal contexts "hier"it works in German too.

Comment: Even in such a informal context, I would add an "bitte": Hier bitte! If the toddler says please, the parent should too ;)

Comment: Yes, in the case you quote. Not necessary between mates though (even if well-raised ;-)

Comment: Note that the full version in German is "Hier *hast* Du X" as opposed to just "Here you *are*."

Comment: Yes, but in both cases the expression is the result of an ellipsis.